# Para que serve o atributo "dirname" no HTML?

Tags: html

Vi na internet um código similar a esse:

```
<form action="/the-action">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" dirname="fname.dir">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Eu nunca tinha visto (até hoje) esse atributo `dirname` em nenhum tutorial, nem sendo usado na prática.

Gostaria de saber pra que ele serve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Esse atributo posta a informação se o texto foi digitado da esquerda para a direita (padrão para nós) ou da direita para a esquerda, sendo usado para receber o valor digitado e saber como foi digitado.

Faz sentido se usado em conjunto com o estilo `direction` e em línguas como árabe.

Veja o exemplo:

```html
<span>Texto para pesquisar:</span>
<input type="text" name="pesquisa" style="direction:RTL" dirname="pesquisaDirecao" />
```

Se submetido o campo, a query string vai receber:

> "?pesquisa=texto&pesquisaDirecao=rtl"

indicando que o valor da pesquisa foi digitado "rtl" ou seja, da direita pra esquerda. Se digitado da esquerda pra direita postaria "pesquisaDirecao=ltr"

Aqui um site explicando e onde é possível testar o submit: https://www.wufoo.com/html5/dirname-attribute/

Answer (score 5):

Segundo o [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_dirname.asp), o atributo `dirname` de um `input` possibilita que a direção do texto de um input seja enviada ao servidor.

Os valores que o servidor deve receber nesse caso deve ser `ltr` caso o texto seja escrito da esquerda para direita, ou `rtl`, caso o texto seja escrito da direita para a esquerda.

Um dos casos onde se usa a escrita da direita para a esquerda é na língua árabe.